# Insert null value in bit(Datatype)

Tags: c#, sql

i'm using this code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" UPDATE memberform set active='" +DBNull.Value+"'",con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But my bit value is False

Comment: and what's your problem?

Comment: remove your begining space of query string `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE memberform set active='" +DBNull.Value+"'",con);`

Comment: It storages False and not Null

Comment: Why not use  `UPDATE memberform set active = null`? And BTW no quotes around `null`!

Comment: @GSerg, it is not MySql.

Comment: Solved thank you. Should i delete answer?

Comment: @Crowcoder It does not matter. Feel free to find this question specifically for SQL Server though.

Comment: @Dim Was there an answer here before? Has one been deleted? If you managed to solve the issue it is encouraged that you answer your own question and leave the answer up for others to see.